# CSS não reflete no navegador

Tags: css, primefaces, front-end, navegador-de-internet, xhtml

Eu comecei um projeto em xhtml Primefaces, só que quando faço alterações no CSS ele não altera no navegador, apenas na IDE.
Projeto no navegador:
[image]

Projeto na IDE Eclipse:
[image]

Comment: CSS dá muito problema de cache. Limpe o cache do navegador e verifique se irá alterar.

Comment: nem acredito que era isso kkk, vlw msm